# Changing variable in c++

Tags: c++

I started learning C++ and I made a simple thing like printing variables etc, but I wanted to make a new value on a variable like in Python:

```
test = "hello world"
print(test)
test = 5
print(test + 6)
```

So I had this:

```cpp
string test = "hello world";
cout << test << "\n";
```

And now I wanted to assign a number to `test`, so I used `int test = 5;`, but I got an error:

> redefinition of 'test' with a different type

Is it possible to assign a new type to a variable somehow?

Comment: not with in a specific scope- you could surround the definition in curly braces

Comment: Why not just make a new variable?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to assign a new type to a variable somehow?

A new *type*, no.  C++ is a statically typed language.  Variable types are specified at compile-time and cannot change at runtime.

For what you are asking, the closest thing available is [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in C++17 and later, which is a fixed class type that can hold different kinds of values at runtime, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using myVariant = std::variant<int, std::string>;

void print(const myVariant &v)
{
    std::visit([](const auto &x) { std::cout << x; }, v);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    myVariant test;
    test = "hello world";
    print(test);
    test = 5;
    print(test);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Cw13bQJsO)

Comment: 15 seconds. Beat me by 15 seconds. Well done :P

Comment: Actually, both of you may be misleading him. What he meant was not `std::variant` since it only considers what data type inside this `<>`. In Python, unlike `c++`, an object or function can have more than one definition.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev • `std::any`?

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev a variable in Python would be more like `std::any` in C++. But that type really should not be used in most cases, in part because it has no concept of what it is actually holding, and doesn't make it easy for the user to get data out of it unless they know exactly what was stored in it to begin with. And as such, `std::any` can't (easily) be printed. Plus, most people don't need that flexibility, they only work with a few types at a time, and `std::variant` is better suited for that purpose, with better type safety and functionality.

Comment: To a new learner, offering _variant_ is like offering them a shotgun to shoot their own foot off. OP, I encourage you to use specific variable for specific things of known types. Don't go mixing random stuff in the same variable.

Comment: @Jeffrey "*... is like offering them a shotgun to shoot their own foot off*" - C++ is good at that.  There are a lot of ways it lets people shoot themselves.  It doesn't hold their hands. "*I encourage you to use specific variable for specific things of known types. Don't go mixing random stuff in the same variable*" - and while that is good advice in general, there are valid use cases for using `variant`, otherwise the C++ committee wouldn't have added it to the standard library.

Comment: @Jeffrey, actually `std::variant` is not that hard. The way he explained is quite enough as surface.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 and newer, [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is a type that can be used to store multiple different types of data. Though you'll have to do a bit of finagling with visitors to get the polymorphic `print` you know from Python.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct PrintVisitor {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(const T& arg) {
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::variant<std::string, int> test = "hello world";
  std::visit(PrintVisitor(), test);
  test = 5;
  std::visit(PrintVisitor(), test);
}
```